# Form not updating database table in cakephp code?

Tags: php, cakephp, sql-update

Hey everyone I am facing this problem the form is not updating when I click submit. It goes in if($this->request->is("post")){....} block but it is not updating.

Here is the code.

PagesController.php

```
public function admin_edit($id=NULL){
    $this->request->data = $this->Page->find("first",array("conditions"=>array("Page.id"=>$id)));
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->request->data["Page"]["id"] = $id;
        if($this->Page->save($this->data)){
            echo "Done";
        }


    }
}
```

admin_edit.php

```
URL -> http://localhost/cakephp_practice/admin/pages/edit/4

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="DataTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Administrator &gt; Edit Page</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

                <?php
                echo $this->Form->create('Page', array("action" => "edit", "method" => "Post",'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'id' => 'editPage'));
                ?>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"> <span class="require">* Please note that all fields that have an asterisk (*) are required. </span></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>Name: <font color="red">*</font></td>
                        <td align="left"><?php echo $this->Form->text('Page.name', array('maxlength' => '254', 'size' => '20', 'label' => '', 'div' => false, 'class' => "form-inbox required")) ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                        </table>

                 <table>       
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td> 
                            <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Submit', array('maxlength' => '50', 'size' => '30', 'label' => '', 'div' => false)) ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>                      
    </table>
```

I have used Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', 'admin'); to automatically resolve url like localhost://project_name/admin/pages/edit to admin_edit action of pages controller.

Edit: When I print_r($this->request->data); in if block then the name field is still containing the old value not the new one I entered. Why is that?

Comment: you need to provide page id  like 1,2,3..to update, but you are providing `editPage`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have checked by echoing $id in if statement it is printing it also I tried using id manually like 4 even then it is not updating.

Comment: only two problem can be there:-1.either id not coming properly. 2or `data` array format is not correct, it need to be like `Array('Page'=>array(...));`

Comment: @AlivetoDie When I print_r($this->request->data) it is containing the old value of Page.name not the new one I entered. Why is that?

Comment: @AlivetoDie The array format is like this Array ( [Page] => Array (....));

Comment: Take a close look at your code and examine what every line in the method body is doing, especially the very first one. How would you expect the data property to contain anything other than the result from the find call? You probably want to make yourself familiar with **https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:-

```
if($this->Page->save($this->data)){
```

Should be:-

```
if($this->Page->save($this->request->data)){
```

However, the first line of your method is overwriting `$this->request->data` which should contain your form data!